# Selecting and editing different paths drawn on canvas differently

Tags: android, canvas

In android I am drawing path creating a custom view and using onDraw() method. But after drawing many paths, I want to identify the paths differently and transform each of them differently. I have identified whether a point is on path or not using rectF and region, but to get contained path (using getBoundaryParh()) in the region is not helping me. So can someone help me with this, I just want to get the object of the selected path by touching on the screen. Thanks.

Comment: first call computeBounds, if your point is inside try to draw your Path on the Canvas spread over the Bitmap, then get a pixel value from that Bitmap, if its alpha byte is != 0 you are lucky luke

Comment: You'll get a better response if your question is more specific.  Please post your code or at least the parts that are not working for you.